# Google Speech API - what is `locations` in the POST URL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

According to the documentation for Google Speech Custom Classes, the URL takes a `locations` parameter, as documented here:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/projects.locations.customClasses/create

The `projects` parameter I assume is just the name of the project on my Google cloud account, but what is `locations` and where can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle is to have the capacity to locate your data in case of specific local regulation.

However, `global` is used in all the example. I tried to put `anything` in the location, and `anything` is a valid location... Not sure that this parameter is active in Preview.

Use global for now, it's the safer and the most compliant with the future. And wait the API in GA to get the official list and an implemented feature.